# How to display Different Images for different Index in TableView?

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, swift

I am developing a simple table app where I want to display Image in every cell and I have done this and one Image is displayed In all cells :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    // Create the cell
    var cell : UITableViewCell = self.TableViewData.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.iteams[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "creme_brelee.jpg")
    return cell
}
```

It works fine but I want to display more Images for different cell and for that I have taken on array:

```
var thumbils : [String] = ["egg_benedict.jpg", "mushroom_risotto.jpg", "full_breakfast.jpg", "hamburger.jpg", "ham_and_egg_sandwich.jpg", "creme_brelee.jpg", "white_chocolate_donut.jpg", "starbucks_coffee.jpg", "vegetable_curry.jpg", "instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg", "noodle_with_bbq_pork.jpg", "japanese_noodle_with_pork.jpg", "green_tea.jpg", "thai_shrimp_cake.jpg", "angry_birds_cake.jpg", "ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg"]
```

but now I dont know how to display different image for different index in tableView.

I know In objective-C we can do like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

But I don't know how to do this in swift.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use below code to fetch an image from array:

```
   cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: thumbils[indexPath.row])
```

Comment: I need 8 minute for that.. :)

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
 cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(self.iteams(indexPath.row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imagesArray = [UIImage]()  
imagesArray.append(UIImage(named: "mypic.png")!)  
cell.imageView?.image = imagesArray[indexPath.row]  
return cell
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Basically you add images to an array and assign an image to each cell depending on the index(position). If you have a static array with items "a,b,c" and you know what image "item a" should have then in your array of images you should add that image first since "item a" is first in the array (position zero)